# How to delete iCloud Backups?

Tags: icloud, backup

I'm not able to clear off the backups on my iCloud account. I had deleted icloud sync from my old iPhone and iPad. It's no longer shows in the iCloud section on both the devices regarding any backup.

Is there any way to delete it off ?

[image]

I checked it out on iCloud.com and It only says backup.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you press that "Manage" button to the right in your first screenshot, do you see a Backups category in the left column?

[image: Manage iCloud data in Mac System Preferences]

I've seen some backups not show up on the iPhone/iPad, but show up on the Mac in this Manage pane. If the backups show up here, click on one and then click delete at the bottom of the list.

Comment: It doesn't show up for me. That's why I asked this question!

Comment: Apologies - I saw that you said it didn't show up in the iCloud section on your devices, but I wasn't sure if you had checked in the macOS Manage section. There used to be a bug (probably still is) that some backups wouldn't show on the iPhone/iPad but do on Mac.

Comment: I think it was a bug. I have deleted the backups now!